# Scons VariantDir() duplicated CPPPATH and LIBPATH when compiling?

Tags: scons

Here's my simple case. I got a source file structure as following:

```
.
├── SConstruct
└── src
    ├── SConscript
    ├── staticLib
    │   ├── classInStaticLib.cpp
    │   ├── classInStaticLib.h
    │   └── SConscript
    └── test.cpp
```

SConstruct:

```
VariantDir('build', 'src', duplicate=0)
SConscript('build/SConscript')
```

src/SConscript:

```
import os
lib = 'staticLib'
SConscript(os.path.join(lib, 'SConscript'))
Program( 'test',
         'test.cpp',
         CPPPATH = lib,
         LIBS = lib,
         LIBPATH = lib )
```

src/staticLib/SConscript:

```
Library('staticLib', 'classInStaticLib.cpp')
```

After I run scons, I got following in shell:

```
g++ -o build/staticLib/classInStaticLib.o -c src/staticLib/classInStaticLib.cpp
ar rc build/staticLib/libstaticLib.a build/staticLib/classInStaticLib.o
ranlib build/staticLib/libstaticLib.a
g++ -o build/test.o -c -Ibuild/staticLib -Isrc/staticLib src/test.cpp
g++ -o build/test build/test.o -Lbuild/staticLib -Lsrc/staticLib -lstaticLib
```

scons completed with no error. But please attention that there're both "-Ibuild/staticLib" and "-Isrc/staticLib" in 4th line, and both "-Lbuild/staticLib" and "-Lsrc/staticLib" in 5th line. There should be only one.

Why this happens ?

Comment: I just asked this question on the SCons-users mailing list to find out if its a bug or intended behavior. See http://four.pairlist.net/pipermail/scons-users/2014-April/002438.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this is happening because you are using the `SCons VariantDir()` function, which causes SCons to look in the build directory. Ive never seen that it uses both the source and variant_dir directories.

The `VariantDir()` function is usually only used when you're not using the `SConscript()` function. Try changing the call to `SConscript()` in your `SConstruct` to use the `variant_dir` parameter and remove the call to `VariantDir()`, as follows:

```
SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir='build', duplicate=0)
```

I would also consider changing the `src/SConscript` as follows:

```
import os
lib = 'staticLib'
SConscript(os.path.join(lib, 'SConscript'),
           variant_dir=os.path.join(lib, 'build'),
           duplicate=0)
Program( 'test',
         'test.cpp',
         CPPPATH = lib,
         LIBS = lib,
         LIBPATH = lib )
```

Here is the result I get when executing scons, which BTW is the same as yours:

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/staticLib/classInStaticLib.o -c src/staticLib/classInStaticLib.cpp
ar rc build/staticLib/libstaticLib.a build/staticLib/classInStaticLib.o
ranlib build/staticLib/libstaticLib.a
g++ -o build/test.o -c -Ibuild/staticLib -Isrc/staticLib src/test.cpp
g++ -o build/test build/test.o -Lbuild/staticLib -Lsrc/staticLib -lstaticLib
scons: done building targets.

$ tree build/
build/
|-- staticLib
|   |-- classInStaticLib.o
|   `-- libstaticLib.a
|-- test
`-- test.o

1 directory, 4 files
```

I have never noticed that SCons does this and cant explain why it does so. I tried playing with different variant_dir options and always get the same. I would say you arent doing anything wrong, and that its a peculiar SCons behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still got the same result.Do you, or anyone else, have time to test on your machine ? Would appreciate a lot.

Comment: @faraday, I tested it last night and again this morning and updated the answer. I get the same results, and its something I never noticed before :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a "normal and intended" effect of using VariantDir() according to a response I got about this on the SCons-users mailing list.

See [four.pairlist.net/pipermail/scons-users/2014-April/002440.html](http://four.pairlist.net/pipermail/scons-users/2014-April/002440.html)

Pawel said: "You may have source files/headers generated (with SWIG for example or by SConf) and they go to variant dir, others are taken directly from source dir, so -Ibuild/staticLib -Isrc/staticLib is correct in my opinion."

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that I have used:

```
import os

def abs_path(rel_path):
    return os.path.join(Dir('.').srcnode().abspath, rel_path)

lib = 'staticLib'
SConscript(os.path.join(lib, 'SConscript'))
Program( 'test',
         'test.cpp',
         CPPPATH = abs_path(lib),
         LIBS = lib,
         LIBPATH = lib )
```

Answer (score -1):

I created this directory structure:

```
stest.cpp
Sconstruct
dira/hello.cpp
dira/hello.h
dirb/hello.cpp
dirb/hello.h
```

My Sconstruct contains this:

```
SOURCES = [ 'stest.cpp', 'hello.cpp' ]
common = Environment ()
a=common.Clone (CPPPATH='#')
a.Repository ('#/dira')
a.Object ('obja/stest.o', 'stest.cpp')
a.Object ('obja/hello.o', 'dira/hello.cpp')
a.Program ('obja/a', ['obja/stest.o', 'obja/hello.o'])
a.Alias ('a', 'obja/a')
b=common.Clone (CPPPATH='#')
b.Repository ('#/dirb')
b.Object ('objb/stest.o', 'stest.cpp')
b.Object ('objb/hello.o', 'dirb/hello.cpp')
b.Program ('objb/b', ['objb/stest.o', 'objb/hello.o'])
b.Alias ('b', 'objb/b')
```

Running `scons -n a b` gives this:

```
g++ -o obja/stest.o -c -I. -Idira -Idirb obja/stest.cpp
g++ -o obja/hello.o -c -I. -Idira -Idirb obja/hello.cpp
g++ -o obja/a obja/stest.o obja/hello.o
g++ -o objb/stest.o -c -I. -Idira -Idirb objb/stest.cpp
g++ -o objb/hello.o -c -I. -Idira -Idirb objb/hello.cpp
g++ -o objb/b objb/stest.o objb/hello.o
```

So, this obviously has nothing to do with `VariantDir()`.