# scons, CPPPATH, and multiple libraries

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, scons

### Problem Description

I am attempting to build a modular system using scons to compile multiple shared libraries, some of which depend on the others.  While I can get this to compile with a few different work-arounds, each has some disadvantages, as described in the Attempted Solutions section.

```
.
├── SConstruct
└── src
    ├── libA
    │   ├── a.cc
    │   ├── a.hh
    │   └── SConscript
    ├── libB
    │   ├── b.cc
    │   ├── b.hh
    │   └── SConscript
    └── SConscript
```

Here, `b.cc` includes `a.hh`, which is the dependency between the two libraries.

The contents of each of the files are shown below.

```
# In SConstruct
VariantDir('build', 'src', duplicate=False)
SConscript('build/SConscript')

# In src/SConscript
env = Environment()
SConscript(['libA/SConscript', 'libB/SConscript'],
           exports='env')

# In src/libA/SConscript
Import('env')

env.Append(CPPPATH=['.'])
env.SharedLibrary('a.cc')

# In src/libB/SConscript
Import('env')

env.Append(CPPPATH=['.'])
env.SharedLibrary('b.cc')
```

Here, I run into an issue.  When I run scons, I have the following result.

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/libA/a.os -c -fPIC -Ibuild/libA -Isrc/libA -Ibuild/libA -Isrc/libA src/libA/a.cc
g++ -o build/libA/liba.so -shared build/libA/a.os
g++ -o build/libB/b.os -c -fPIC -Ibuild/libB -Isrc/libB -Ibuild/libB -Isrc/libB src/libB/b.cc
src/libB/b.cc:3:16: fatal error: a.hh: No such file or directory
 #include "a.hh"
                ^
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [build/libB/b.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

I know from [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217008/scons-variantdir-duplicated-cpppath-and-libpath-when-compiling) that the duplication of `-Ibuild/libA` and `-Isrc/libA` makes sense, and is intended.  However, `-Isrc/libA` is passed twice when compiling `a.cc`, and not at all when compiling `b.cc`.

---

### Attempted Solutions

This seems to be caused by passing a string into `CPPPATH`, rather than a `Dir()` node.  The string is then expanded with the path to the current SConscript later, rather than expanding with the current SConscript.  To avoid this, I modified `CPPPATH=['.']` to `CPPPATH=[Dir('.')]` in `src/libA/SConscript` and `src/libB/SConscript`.  This does not work, because then only `build/libA` is included in the CPPPATH, not `src/libA`, as shown below.

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
g++ -o build/libA/a.os -c -fPIC -Ibuild/libA -Ibuild/libB src/libA/a.cc
g++ -o build/libA/liba.so -shared build/libA/a.os
g++ -o build/libB/b.os -c -fPIC -Ibuild/libA -Ibuild/libB src/libB/b.cc
src/libB/b.cc:3:16: fatal error: a.hh: No such file or directory
 #include "a.hh"
                ^
compilation terminated.
scons: *** [build/libB/b.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

Second, I tested this with `duplicate=False`.  In combination with the first test, using `Dir('.')`, this successfully compiles the libraries.  However, this is not ideal, because any debug symbols then point to source files within the `build` directory.  For large projects, after compiling, I like to delete the `build` directory to save space, which then makes debugging harder, since gdb can no longer find the source files.

Next, I tried using abolute paths.  That is, in libA, I add `CPPPATH=['#/src/libA']`, and in libB, I add `CPPPATH=['#/src/libB']`.  This successfully compiles, with `duplicate=False`.  However, this is intended as a library that could potentially be included from many different top-level SConstructs.  By hard-coding the path into the library's SConscript, it restricts the usage of this library.

Finally, I tried not using `VariantDir` at all.  In addition to using `Dir('.')` as the path for each library, this works, but leaves all of the intermediate files in the `src` directory.  This clutters up the directory structure, and makes it very tricky to maintain multiple builds (e.g. debug/release).

Is there a design usage that would avoid these issues?

Comment: Can you please use the `variant_dir` keyword as advised in chap 15 "Separating Source and Build Directories" of the [UserGuide](http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-user.html) and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Certainly.  Replacing the contents of the top-level SConstruct with `SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir='build', duplicate=False)` leads to the same behavior as when using `VariantDir` directly.  That is, when using `CPPPATH=['.']` in the SConscripts, the include path passed to the compiler is `-Isrc/libA -Ibuild/libA -Isrc/libA -Ibuild/libA', with repetition, and when using `CPPPATH=[Dir('.')]`, then the include path is `-Ibuild/libA -Ibuild/libB`, without the `src` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You state that "*By hard-coding the path into the library's SConscript, it restricts the usage of this library.*". But what's the alternative? At some point in your build description you have to get specific about which paths should get searched for implicit dependencies (like headers or libs). And if you then move your folders around, the build will break...independent of your build tool choice.

Using SCons "#" paths, specified starting from the top-level SConstruct, works fine and is one solution to your problem.
The other alternative would be to use relative paths, starting from your current SConstruct upwards or downwards. So for `src/libB/SConscript` you could use:

```
Import('env')

env.AppendUnique(CPPPATH=['.', '../libA'])
env.SharedLibrary('b.cc')
```

This would then at least allow you to move "`libA`" and "`libB`" simultaneously to a new place. But I don't think you can do better than that...

Comment: Thank you.  I had been hoping that the path could be created just from the path to the current SConscript, as given in the top-level SConscript, and the relative path in the SConscript.  This seems to be the intended behavior, because all other paths are given relative to the current SConscript, and there is some attempt being made at merging the two paths, which is done correctly in some cases.  At the moment, it seems to be a bug, since the full CPPPATH is being generated using the path to the SConscript where it is being used, rather than the one where it is defined.

Comment: Feel free to come to our User mailing list and report the "bug", please include a MWE. After a short discussion, we'll then add the issue to our bug tracker (Tigris).